# Bundle complaining about path of local gem on remote server when deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mercurial, capistrano, bundler

So, i have a mercurial repository that has a main project and 2 extensions to the project. lets call project A and the extensions B and C. Thus, the repo has 3 folders, A, B, and C inside the repo, and in my local computer the folders are in "~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/". In project A's gemfile, i have the following lines:

```
gem "B", :path => "~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/B/"
gem "C", :path => "~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/C/"
```

When i deploy with Capistrano, i get the error: "The path `/home/username/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/B` does not exist." which is not surprising at all. However, I don't really know how to fix this issue so that the path in the remote server and my localhost are the same. the proper directory on the remote server is "~/rails/B". If i changed this server side it would just get overwritten the next time i deploy. I could technically make a folder called rails on my local computer so that they are both in the same directory structure but that doesn't really seem like an elegant solution.

I read about splitting the 3 folders into their own repositories but on mercurials site it says that this is bad practice.

Is there any way to fix this without having to move my project folder in my localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using git instead of mercurial. Since bundler likes git and git can handle multiple repositories easily in a project, i switched to it. I split the project into 3 repositories on git.

My gemfile looks like this now (after adding SSH keys to bitbucket):

```
gem "B", :git => "git@bitbucket.org:username/B.git", :branch => 'master'
gem "C", :git => "git@bitbucket.org:username/C.git", :branch => 'master'
```